# How to get the average of the total values from json file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I have a json file with following data

```
"[{\"ts\":1581669310,\"cpu\":45,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1443.55,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null},{\"ts\":1581669311,\"cpu\":34,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1441,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null},{\"ts\":1581669312,\"cpu\":40,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1399.83,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null},{\"ts\":1581669313,\"cpu\":28,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1430.51,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null},{\"ts\":1581669314,\"cpu\":37,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1378.81,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":0,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":26.5527,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null},{\"ts\":1581669316,\"cpu\":54,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1384.85,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":27,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":199.819,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":756,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":2254},{\"ts\":1581669317,\"cpu\":48,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1378.42,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":16,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":255.646,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":11005,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":6031},{\"ts\":1581669319,\"cpu\":41,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1303.2,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":12,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":321.868,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":13585,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":10298},{\"ts\":1581669320,\"cpu\":41,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1373.43,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":8,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":236.064,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":30499,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":12948}]"
```

The number of datas can vary each time. So I wnated to take average for each value.

> Like the average value for - ts, cpu, mem, mema, batt, temp,
>   comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu, comuniqlocacatalogue_mem,
>   comuniqlocacatalogue_netr and comuniqlocacatalogue_nets.

How can I able to get it. Please help. Also the values for each one will change and total times the the value comes also changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for finding average evrey key in your list, but do not calculate null value in process

```js
var data = JSON.parse("[{\"ts\":1581669310,\"cpu\":45,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1443.55,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":1,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null}, {\"ts\":1581669311,\"cpu\":34,\"mem\":3550.67,\"mema\":1441,\"batt\":100,\"temp\":21.4,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_cpu\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_mem\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_netr\":null,\"comuniqlocacatalogue_nets\":null}]");

var avgerage = Array.from(data.reduce(
  (acc, obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce( 
      (acc, key) => typeof obj[key] == "number"
          ? acc.set(key, (acc.get(key) || []).concat(obj[key]))
          : acc,
  acc),
new Map()), 
  ([name, values]) =>
      ({ name, average: values.reduce( (a,b) => a+b ) / values.length })
);

console.log(avgerage);
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet might help you

```js
const data = require("./path/to/your/json/file");
const averageTs = data.reduce((acc, current) => acc + current.ts, 0)/data.length;
const averageCpu = data.reduce((acc, current) => acc + current.cpu, 0)/data.length;
// do the same for other values
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty similar to other answers, only hold two decimals.

```js
let foo = [{
  a: 10,
  b: 10.10,
  c: 'dfdf',
  d: true
},
{
  a: 20,
  b: 20.20,
  c: 'dfdf',
  d: true
}]


function obj_avg(data) {
  let ret = data.reduce((acc, record) => {
    Object.keys(record).forEach(field => {
      if (typeof record[field] === 'number') {
        if (!acc[field]) {
          acc[field] = []
        }
        acc[field].push(record[field])
      }
    })
    return acc
  }, {})

  Object.keys(ret).forEach(key => {
    let avg = ret[key].reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / ret[key].length
    ret[key] = Math.round((avg + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
  })
  return ret
}

console.log(obj_avg(foo))
```